# Elasticsearch range query option for C#/.net consumer

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest to query elasticsearch to fetch a list of documents that belong in a certain date range. This is what I have but I am not sure how to change it to provide date range.

```
var searchResults = elasticSearchClient
    .Search<Product>(s => s.From(0)
        .Size(10)
        .Query(q => q.Term(p => p.SellDate.....)));
```

I want to filter results so that I get the data with "SellDate" in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following:

```
q => q.Range(v => v.OnField("myDocs.SellDate").From(fromRange).To(toRange))
```